# Override class of CGridColumn

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

i am just trying to override the class of **CGridColumn** but somehow its not overriding.

my code is below

```
<?php

Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridColumn');

class CGridColumnCustom extends CGridColumn
{   
    // new variable that will bind near header
    public $headerFilter;


    public function renderHeaderCell()
    {
        $this->headerHtmlOptions['id']=$this->id;
        echo CHtml::openTag('th',$this->headerHtmlOptions);
        $this->renderHeaderCellContent();
        $this->renderFilterHeaderCellContent();
        echo "</th>";
    }       

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # custom function that will concat with  renderHeaderCellContent at renderHeaderCell
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function renderFilterHeaderCellContent()
    {
        echo trim($this->headerFilter)!=='' ? $this->headerFilter : $this->grid->blankDisplay;
    }

}
?>
```

and i added this file(CGridColumnCustom.php) in components folder and i also imported this file in CustomerModule.php file like below

```
$this->setImport(array(
            'customer.components.*',        
        ));
```

but when i am trying to implement my custom function like below in view file

```
'columns'=>array(
        array(
        'name'  => 'Name',
        'value' => '$data->Name',
        'type'  => 'raw',
        'headerFilter'=> '<span class="name-filter-head" onclick="alert(\'test\');">&nbsp;CustomFilter</span>',
        ),
```

then it will give below error

> Property "CDataColumn.headerFilter" is not defined.

But if i directly added those changes on Core file at **CGridColumn.php** at gii.widgets.grid then its working fine but i don't want to change in core file.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: You're not telling GridView to use your custom column so it uses CDataColumn by default (which doesn't have headerFilter prop). You should specify 'class' as in the answer below. Perhaps you should specify the full path i.e. `'class' => 'ext.CGridColumnCustom',` (or where you placed it). Something along these lines

Comment: @snegostup i also tried with `'class' => 'CGridColumnCustom'` and i added this CGridColumnCustom.php in my componant folder. do i need to put it on extension folder ?

Comment: I believe you should specify full alias to the class no matter where you place it. If you placed it in components try `'class' => 'application.components.CGridColumnCustom'`

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it following way:

First thing (actually not sure if it's relevant, but name your class `CGridCustomColumn` with word 'Column' on the end.

Second, view should be like this then:

```
'columns'=>array(
        array(
             'header' => 'CGridCustom',
             'class' => 'CGridCustomColumn'
             'value' => '$data->Name'
             'type' => 'raw'
        ),
```